# Pyglet large sprites glitch

Tags: python, linux, pyglet

I am working on a simple game in Python, using the Pyglet graphics library. I have an image, 6000x300 pixels, that I want to use as a scrolling background for the game. At the moment, I have made a sprite with the image and move it left and right depending on the player's position. The problem I have is that the sprite is glitchy: sometimes the 400 or so pixels at the start are duplicated several times along the length of it, and the motion of the sprite is sometimes jerky and sometimes smooth.

**Is this expected behavior for an image of that size? Is there a workaround? If not, can anyone suggest an better way to make a scrolling background?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like vsync, but not really. Could you take a picture of it? Can you show us the code that you use to render and move the sprites?

Comment: @Torxed I can send a video, but only when I get home in an hour and a half. A photo wouldn't really show what I mean.

Comment: Video would do too, just make it short and as clear as possible of the problem. And post your code ^^

Comment: Ok. Also the code is VERY long, you can check it out at https://github.com/Jachdich/magical-adventures-of-wtf and I am currently working on shortening it to just the bare minimum. And idk if the GitHub repo is up to date, again I'll do it when I get internet at home.

Comment: @Torxed nevermind, I fixed it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a strange one. I got home and ran the program on my newer desktop (my laptop is about 8 or more years old...) with the intention of making a video to help to explain the problem, and guess what? It runs perfectly. Must be a bug with Pyglet and very old hardware...